# Unable to create an object of type 'AppDbContext'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

For learning, I'm trying to do a social login.

I use for example https://tecknoworks.com/how-to-integrate-social-login-in-a-web-api-solution/
following this example i cannot create migration when doing Add-Migration InitialCreate I get error

"Unable to create an object of type 'AppDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see [https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728"](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728%22)

while searching found advice to use add-migration initial -verbose on it i get error

"An unexpected return type was encountered while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Method 'CreateHostBuilder (string [])' should return an object of type 'IHostBuilder'. Continuing without the application service provider."

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args);

            using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
                var loggerFactory = services.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
                var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();
                try
                {
                    var environment = services.GetRequiredService<IWebHostEnvironment>();

                    if (environment.IsDevelopment())
                    {
                        var context = services.GetRequiredService<Infrastructure.AppDbContext>();
                        MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion.ExecuteAsync(context).Wait();
                    }
                }
                catch (AppException ex)
                {
                    logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred creating/updating the DB.");
                }
            }

            host.Run();
        }

        private static IWebHost CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
    }
```

code AppDbContext

```
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<AppUser>(entity => { entity.ToTable(name: "tr_Users"); });
            builder.Entity<IdentityRole>(entity => { entity.ToTable(name: "tr_Roles"); });
            builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>(entity => { entity.ToTable("tr_UserRoles"); });
            builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>(entity => { entity.ToTable("tr_UserClaims"); });
            builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>(entity => { entity.ToTable("tr_UserLogins"); });
            builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>(entity => { entity.ToTable("tr_UserTokens"); });
            builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>(entity => { entity.ToTable("tr_RoleClaims"); });

            builder.ApplyConfiguration(new AppUserConfiguration());
        }
    }
```

ConfigureServices

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors();

            ConfigureSwagger(services);

            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(it =>
            {
                it.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Database:ConnectionString"]);
            },
                 ServiceLifetime.Transient
            );

            CreateIdentityIfNotCreated(services);

            ConfigureAuthenticationSettings(services);

            services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();

            services.AddMvc(options => options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true);
        }
```

in the database table [__EFMigrationsHistory] is created

Comment: Can you share `ConfigureServices` method in your `Start up`?

Comment: @Yinqiu added ConfigureServices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `IWebHost CreateWebHostBuilder` method to return `IHostBuilder` (and `Main` accordingly), in your case it will look something like this:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();
    .....
    host.Run();
}
```

Also I've changed `CreateWebHostBuilder` to use `Host` instead of `WebHost` as written in ["Migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.0" docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#hostbuilder-replaces-webhostbuilder).

Comment: @Евгений was glad to help!